# JavaScript Design Pattern: String consisting of blanks with join(' '). Afterwards .split(' ') - Purpose?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've seen this pattern on CodePen:

```
var demo = new Array(3);

demo = demo.join(' ').split(' ');
```

**Can someone please explain me this pattern?**

Is it just for getting an array with n empty-strings? 
Or does it target something else?

The CodePen in which I've seen it:

http://codepen.io/pavlovsk/pen/wWVqaq

Please see Function nJoin() .

Comment: `Is it just for getting an array with n empty-strings? Or does it target something else?` -> Yes.

Comment: haha is it A or B? Yes :D @jAndy

Comment: `Array(3)` is a sparse/empty Array with length 3, after joining and splitting you have an Array with three `""` in it -> Array is not empty anymore; *although this might sound weird when talking about empty strings.* check `0 in demo` or `demo.hasOwnProperty(0)` or `Object.keys(demo)`before and after this task. And especially `demo.forEach(console.log)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making an array with empty strings with this operation.

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> `map` calls a provided `callback` function **once for each element** in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values, including [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined). It is not called for missing elements of the array (that is, indexes that have never been set, which have been deleted or which have never been assigned a value).

```js
var demo = new Array(3);

console.log(demo.length);
console.log(demo[0]);
console.log(typeof demo[0]);

demo = demo.join(' ').split(' ');

console.log(demo.length);
console.log(demo[0]);
console.log(typeof demo[0]);

// map over an array with sparsed values.
var a = new Array(3),
    b = a.map((_, i) => i);
console.log(a[0]);
console.log(b);

// map over an array with undefined values.
var x = Array.apply(null, { length: 3 }),
    y = x.map((_, i) => i);
console.log(x[0]);
console.log(y);
```

Comment: If this really needs to be answered, you should mention that one cannot `.map()` over an Array with `undefined` values. That is why the original Author of that code (CodePen) transformed that Array into empty strings beforehand.

Comment: Okay. I think I get it. One could say it's an alternative way of having a loop? One could also use " for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) "? But that wouldn't be so cool ...

Comment: for loops with an index does work, because the length property of the array is given with ``new Array(3)`. but there is no initialised element in it.

Comment: Well I didn't express myself 100% correct above. One *could* `.map()` over `undefined` values, if those values were in a defined Array. The problem arrises as soon as you create an Array with `new Array()`, because it just will set a `.length` property, but it won't fill anything into it. Hence you cannot iterate respectively map over that. For that reason alone, the Author filled that newly created array with dummy values.

Answer (score 4):

It's just to create an array with empty strings. Note that, with es6, you can make this more easy and more readable by using [Array.prototype.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) instead:

```
var a = new Array(3).fill("");
console.log(a); // ["", "", ""]
```

See the browser support table, it's a new feature at the time of this writing.